# Como fazer commit de um arquivo específico em git?

Tags: git

Observe a imagem a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero *commitar* somente o segundo arquivo.

Como faço? Qual o comando no git?

Comment: Algo como `git add <file>`?

Comment: Para referências futuras, a resposta está explícita na própria imagem da pergunta. Imediatamente acima da lista de arquivos em vermelho há "*Changes not staged for commit*", seguido de dois comandos possíveis. Um para adicionar os arquivos desejados, outro para descartar as alterações de um arquivo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Inclusive eu acho que a pergunta deveria ser fechada como "erro de digitação" (ok, não tem digitação, mas né). A resposta responde, ok, deixemos ela lá, mas não vejo necessidade de manter a pergunta aberta.

Comment: Fiz uma edição que julguei ter dado mais utilidade à pergunta para futuros leitores. Ainda que "o erro seja autoexplicativo", como na maioria das vezes. Se achar indevida, pode reverter na [revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/368443/revisions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primeiro adicione o arquivo especificado da segunda linha na staging area, no caso é o `context.xml`:

```
git add proj/WebContent/META-INF/context.xml
```

Após adicioná-lo, execute o commit

```
git commit -m "Mensagem"
```